# Azure SAML SSO Unique User Identifier incorrect in response

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml, idp

So I created an enterprise application and have it configured for SAML based SSO. As I understand it, I've configured it so that the Unique User Identifier (Name ID) should be set the the email of the user [within Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjrhu.png).

When I attempted to login to test or use my new application through the portal, I can see that the NameID value in the response is actually set to a random string of characters (zReN4-W7ufefDDEh4pJ19K7pcMV84O5RKHSeOQ6wArU) which I assume unique identifies my user. I've tries altering the source attribute of the Name ID as well as the name identifer format but it always comes back as the exact same string in the response.

The application I'm trying to log into requires that the name ID be set to the user's email address and I don't understand why it's not being shown that way in the response. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The NameID value is a targeted identifier that is directed only to the service provider that is the audience for the token. It is persistent - it can be revoked, but is never reassigned. It is also opaque, in that it does not reveal anything about the user and cannot be used as an identifier for attribute queries.

Generally, if the user does not have value in mail attribute, then Azure AD would send persistent format for Name ID and set random value in it.

For more information on the SAML Protocol can go through this [article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol.md) and similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60538054/azuread-idp-initiated-saml-always-return-nameid-formatpersistent-instead-of-nam)