# How do I add a user attribute in a SAML SSO response

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml

I am working on using Azure AD B2C as the Identity Provider for a custom site that also provides SSO for a Blackboard Learn LMS site. Blackboard can do SSO through SAML, so I am using those capabilities within B2C. Unfortunately, SAML is not a protocol I am well-acquainted with, so my ability to troubleshoot is limited. I am working off of the tutorial at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Everything is going mostly pretty well, but I am trying to map user attributes that are shared with Blackboard so that when a new user is created, they have at least a basic profile. There are a couple attributes that are coming through naturally in this tutorial, but I am trying to specify the username for the profile (specs require that it is the email address), and I am not having any luck.

I added the `OutputClaim` named "userPrincipalName" in the SignUpOrSignIn policy (see code below), as it has the appropriate value coming from B2C, but according to a Blackboard test page, it is not among the values that are being sent in the SAML response (see screenshot further down).

```
  ...
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="objectId"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="objectId" ExcludeAsClaim="true"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
  ...
```

[image: [Screenshot]]

Are there further steps that need to happen? I have tinkered with the TrustFrameworkExtensions (and Base) here an there, as well, but to no avail, and I can't find any described process for adding new attributes to the SAML response. Does anyone have an example/tutorial that could walk me through it?

(I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492662/azure-saml-sso-unique-user-identifier-incorrect-in-response) and an answer indicates that I might need to change the NameIdFormat. I can see that the format in my B2C app metadata is incorrect as it suggests, but I'm not sure how I would go about changing it)

### Update

Based on @JasSuri-MSFT's suggestion, I set a (non-empty) default value for the UPN, and sure enough, that default value came through. So it would seem that the problem is that the UPN is null.

This is strange, as in the edit page for the user in B2C, there is clearly a UPN value. It also highlights another oddity that I had not mentioned. But there are other `OutputClaims` listed in that policy that are not being included either. One of them, `email`, I explicitly provided a value for, and it is apparently presenting as null as well.

Clearly there is another piece in the plumbing somewhere that I don't have established.

Comment: You’re doing the change in the right place, but if userPrincipalName is null, you won’t see it in the SAML response. Try add a defaultValue to it. Also UPN of a B2C user will normally be useless (randomguid@yourtenant.com).

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT, thanks. I tried a defaultValue, as you suggested, and it did come through. So it appears that the UPN is null to the SAML response. However, when setting up this user, I explicitly set values for that, and the email, so B2C *does* have values for them. Is there anything else that is needed to push those values through the SAML protocol?

Comment: You need to actually read the value at some point in the journey. One of the technical profiles executed as part of your user journey needs to have the claim (UPN) set as an output claim. UPN would normally come from a technical profile without a protocol, signifying a read/write operation from the directory. You never set the value for UPN normally for B2C users, it’s generated for you. The email is usually stored in the identities collection, referred to as signInNames.emailAddress in custom policy. Look at the AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId technical profile.

Comment: The Azure portal always shows UPN as one of the signInNames from the identity collection for B2C users. It is not actually the UPN attribute, hence my first comment.

Comment: You need to inspect the user with graph api and use the correct raw attribute names in the custom policy.

Answer (score 0):

Add `signInNames.emailAddress` as an output claim in `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId` and add `signInNames.emailAddress` as an output claim in the `RelyingParty` section. Use a `partnerClaimType` in the output claim in the RelyingParty to issue the claim with the name you like into the SAML Response.

```xml
 <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
```

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io/wiki/LocalAccount-Sign-In-and-Sign-Up-policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#identities-attribute

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#outputclaims

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll hopefully be circling back around to this later today or tomorrow. I'll give an update, depending on what I find. Thanks!